# What is the specified behavior of including a standard C header, in C++ code, inside a linkage-specification (extern "C", extern "C++")?

Tags: c++, c, header-files, linkage

Typically one includes standard library headers in C++ in the global namespace, outside of any `extern`s, like so:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() { }
```

But what's specified to happen if you include a standard library header inside one?  For example:

```
extern "C" {
#include <stdint.h>
}
int main() { }
```

or

```
extern "C++" {
#include <stdint.h>
}
int main() { }
```

Is it specified what should happen in either case, or is it implementation-defined or even undefined?

C++11 17.6.2.3p1 says that C++ standard library headers put stuff in `extern "C++"`, but my tentative reading is that this doesn't apply to C headers like `<stdint.h>`.  C++11 17.6.2.2p3 says headers can only be `#include`d outside of any "external declaration"; this phrase appears only this one place in C++11, so I'm not sure if it might apply here.  (I'm assuming C99 has nothing to say about this.)

(For my particular case it isn't an option to use C++'s `<c*>` standard headers, so I really need to know the semantics only for the old-school C headers.)

Comment: on what broken implementation is it impossible to use the C++ `<c*>` headers? And why would following the Standard on such a broken implementation be relevant at all?

Comment: @rubenvb Developing in Embedded/Kernel would often pose similar limits, either technically or by choice

Comment: @icepack Sure, freestanding implementations aren't required to include all portions of the standard library, but if the `*.h` can be provided then so can the corresponding `c*` header. Why would any implementation choose not to have both?

Comment: @bames53 you may want not to allow the C++ linkage by not having extern "C++", for example.

Comment: @icepack I don't understand how that applies. Linkage will not differ between `c*` headers and `*.h` headers. If an implementation disallows C++ linkage for `*.h` headers then it can do the same for `c*` headers.

Comment: @bames53 Maybe it's not the best comparison. But there other differences, such as having everything in std namespace for cstdio - that wouldn't be valid if only C is allowed

Comment: @icepack but we're talking about a C++ implementation. Of course `c*` headers won't be allowed by a C compiler. Neither will `extern "C"`.

Comment: @bames53 I mean that it's common situation to use C++ compiler over an essentially C code and have benefits of better type checking. In fact until not so long ago MS recommendation for writing Kernel drivers in C++ was to use it only a superset of C compiler.

Comment: @rubenvb This particular case, at present, happens to be for a reimplementation of a standard C header with uneven support across compilers (namely, `<stdint.h>`).  This could perhaps be changed to be a reimplementation of either that header, or of `<cstdint>` if compiling C++ code, but since we started out reimplementing the C header, it's likely easier to continue doing that than to switch (and have to update all users for the possibility that the platform's `<cstdint>` only defines `std::int32_t` and not `::int32_t`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard doesn't say anything about C headers that are not part of C++. Previous to C++-11, `stdint.h`/`cstdint` was not part of C++. It's up to that header how it behaves when included from C++ code.

If you're asking about C headers that *are* part of C++, the only difference between `*.h` and `c*` is that the former isn't required to add its identifiers to the `std` namespace (it's optional whether it does so or not,) while the latter is *required* to do so (and it can optionally also add them to the global namespace.) There's no other difference. You shouldn't include a standard `*.h` header inside an `extern "C"` block, as the headers themselves take care of using C linkage where needed.

If you have non-standard C headers you want to include from C++ code, then you must inspect those headers to determine whether you need to include them `extern "C"` or not on a case by case basis.

Comment: The `*.h` headers are only required to add the names to the global namespace but may also add them to the `std` namespace. The `c*` headers are only required to add the names to the `std` namespace but may also add them to the global namespace.